# R data.table. Apply function on moving window with group by and condition

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have data table DT with time series, flag and different grouping tables (category, brand, size, etc.)

I want to apply min function grouped by category (configurable) in a moving window size 4 (configurable), ordered by date, If all flags in this window is FALSE, than I need to find minimum value in this window and mark it as TRUE.
What is the data.table way to do that and not to use a lot of for loops?

Original table

```
zz <- "index    date    value   category    flag
1   01.01.2018  20  green   FALSE
2   01.01.2018  8   RED FALSE
3   02.01.2018  21  green   FALSE
4   02.01.2018  5   RED FALSE
5   03.01.2018  19  green   FALSE
6   03.01.2018  5   RED TRUE
7   04.01.2018  17  green   FALSE
8   04.01.2018  7   RED FALSE
9   05.01.2018  19  green   FALSE
10  05.01.2018  8   RED FALSE
11  06.01.2018  18  green   FALSE
12  06.01.2018  8   RED FALSE
13  07.01.2018  17  green   FALSE
14  07.01.2018  8   RED FALSE
15  08.01.2018  16  green   TRUE
16  08.01.2018  4   RED TRUE
17  09.01.2018  15  green   TRUE
18  09.01.2018  4   RED FALSE
19  10.01.2018  14  green   TRUE
20  10.01.2018  6   RED FALSE
21  11.01.2018  13  green   TRUE
22  11.01.2018  8   RED FALSE
23  12.01.2018  14  green   FALSE
24  12.01.2018  9   RED FALSE
25  13.01.2018  13  green   TRUE
26  13.01.2018  5   RED TRUE
27  14.01.2018  14  green   FALSE
28  14.01.2018  6   RED FALSE
29  15.01.2018  12  green   TRUE
30  15.01.2018  4   RED FALSE
31  16.01.2018  14  green   FALSE
32  16.01.2018  4   RED TRUE
33  17.01.2018  13  green   TRUE
34  17.01.2018  2   RED TRUE"

Data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
```

Expected result:

```
index   date    value   category    flag
1   01.01.2018  20  green   FALSE
2   01.01.2018  8   RED FALSE
3   02.01.2018  21  green   FALSE
4   02.01.2018  5   RED FALSE
5   03.01.2018  19  green   FALSE
6   03.01.2018  5   RED TRUE
7   04.01.2018  17  green   TRUE #marked
8   04.01.2018  7   RED TRUE #marked
9   05.01.2018  19  green   FALSE
10  05.01.2018  8   RED FALSE
11  06.01.2018  18  green   FALSE
12  06.01.2018  8   RED FALSE
13  07.01.2018  17  green   FALSE
14  07.01.2018  8   RED FALSE
15  08.01.2018  16  green   TRUE
16  08.01.2018  4   RED TRUE
17  09.01.2018  15  green   TRUE
18  09.01.2018  4   RED TRUE #marked
19  10.01.2018  14  green   TRUE
20  10.01.2018  6   RED FALSE
21  11.01.2018  13  green   TRUE
22  11.01.2018  8   RED FALSE
23  12.01.2018  14  green   FALSE
24  12.01.2018  9   RED FALSE
25  13.01.2018  13  green   TRUE
26  13.01.2018  5   RED TRUE
27  14.01.2018  14  green   FALSE
28  14.01.2018  6   RED FALSE
29  15.01.2018  12  green   TRUE
30  15.01.2018  4   RED FALSE
31  16.01.2018  14  green   FALSE
32  16.01.2018  4   RED TRUE
33  17.01.2018  13  green   TRUE
34  17.01.2018  2   RED TRUE
```

Comment: You might want to give data in an [easy-to-paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) form.

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible data? Use dput()

Comment: @RomanLuštrik. I've modified to make it ease-to-pase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you need to loop over all the rows, actually I believe it is enough to go over the windows size sequence

```
library(data.table)
Data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
setDT(Data) #convert to data.table by reference
Data.list <- split(Data, by = "category") #split into list of 2 data.tables by the category variable
windowSize <- 4
Data.list <- lapply(Data.list, function(i) {
  for (k in seq_len(windowSize)) { #loop over the window size sequence
    setorder(i, date) #make sure data is ordered by date
    groups <- 1:ceiling((nrow(i) - (k-1))/windowSize)
    repeats <- c(rep(windowSize, each = floor((nrow(i) - (k-1))/windowSize)), (nrow(i) - (k-1)) %% windowSize)
    repeats <- repeats[repeats !=0]
    i[, window := NA_integer_]
    i[k:nrow(i), window := rep(groups, times = repeats)] #createing the grouping dummy variable
    i[, check := !any(flag), by = window] #check for interuption in the windows sequence
    i[i[, .I[value == min(value)], by = .(check, window)][!is.na(window) & check][1]$V1, flag2 := TRUE]
  }
  return(i)
})
Data <- rbindlist(Data.list)
Data[, c("window", "check") := NULL]
setorder(Data, date)
```

Which returns:

```
 #    index       date value category  flag flag2
 #1:     1 01.01.2018    20    green FALSE    NA
 #2:     2 01.01.2018     8      RED FALSE    NA
 #3:     3 02.01.2018    21    green FALSE    NA
 #4:     4 02.01.2018     5      RED FALSE    NA
 #5:     5 03.01.2018    19    green FALSE    NA
 #6:     6 03.01.2018     5      RED  TRUE    NA
 #7:     7 04.01.2018    17    green FALSE  TRUE
 #8:     8 04.01.2018     7      RED FALSE  TRUE
 #9:     9 05.01.2018    19    green FALSE    NA
#10:    10 05.01.2018     8      RED FALSE    NA
#11:    11 06.01.2018    18    green FALSE    NA
#12:    12 06.01.2018     8      RED FALSE    NA
#13:    13 07.01.2018    17    green FALSE    NA
#14:    14 07.01.2018     8      RED FALSE    NA
#15:    15 08.01.2018    16    green  TRUE    NA
#16:    16 08.01.2018     4      RED  TRUE    NA
#17:    17 09.01.2018    15    green  TRUE    NA
#18:    18 09.01.2018     4      RED FALSE  TRUE
#19:    19 10.01.2018    14    green  TRUE    NA
#20:    20 10.01.2018     6      RED FALSE    NA
#21:    21 11.01.2018    13    green  TRUE    NA
#22:    22 11.01.2018     8      RED FALSE    NA
#23:    23 12.01.2018    14    green FALSE    NA
#24:    24 12.01.2018     9      RED FALSE    NA
#25:    25 13.01.2018    13    green  TRUE    NA
#26:    26 13.01.2018     5      RED  TRUE    NA
#27:    27 14.01.2018    14    green FALSE    NA
#28:    28 14.01.2018     6      RED FALSE    NA
#29:    29 15.01.2018    12    green  TRUE    NA
#30:    30 15.01.2018     4      RED FALSE    NA
#31:    31 16.01.2018    14    green FALSE    NA
#32:    32 16.01.2018     4      RED  TRUE    NA
#33:    33 17.01.2018    13    green  TRUE    NA
#34:    34 17.01.2018     2      RED  TRUE    NA
#    index       date value category  flag flag2
```